# Legal to share malware code/sell malware products?

Tags: criminal-law, terms-of-service, hacking

I program / rewrite (from security analysis / reverse engineering) different kinds of malware software as a hobby.
Those include some pretty malicious things like ransomware extortion viruses, banking trojans, exploit kits e.g.
I share the source code on github, and it is starting to cause attention. Can I have trouble with that?
What if I want to sell some of these malicious programs as a service (exe files/malware builders that work for a given period of time)?

I know this is controversial and that the majority of people will use my software to do harm, but it is extremely valuable for security analysts.
Anyway, can I be sure that with proper TOS I can distribute any kind of software or should I worry?
Also I live eastern Europe but intend to sell worldwide.